# How to read excel file in SharePoint and write data in to new file on same sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, excel-services

I'm now creating a microsoft form which will accept excel file upload.

All files will be uploaded to SharePoint site folder, that all successful.

and now I want to read all rows from each file (there are 20 -30 rows each file) to create summary of all files data.

Please kindly guide me how to accomplish this task and if there are any caution or concern that I need to be aware of, please advise.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could try to use flow to achieve this.

Comment: Actually I try with that but not success . Dont know how to read only row I want